# Re-opening a class, where to put this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class that I want to re-open that is in a gem.

I put it in:

/lib/ClassName.rb

```
class ClassName
  class << self
    def some_method(a)
    end
  end
end
```

Now if I call this class method, it says its an undefined method.

I do have autoload set to the /lib folder.

Is this the wrong way to do this?

Comment: `lib` isn't in the autoload path in rails 3.  is that your issue?

Comment: did you do a `require 'ClassName'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that sometimes I need to manually require certain files (especially one's that *monkey patch* existing classes/modules), even though the `lib` folder is being configured to autoload. I have yet to figure out why exactly.

To get around this, in `config/initializers/application.rb` (create it if necessary) I would require the file manually:

```
require 'ClassName'
```